# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I'm using OLEDB provider for ADO.Net connecting to an Oracle database.  In my loop, I am doing an insert:

```
insert into ps_tl_compleave_tbl values('2626899', 0, TO_DATE('01/01/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'LTKN', 'LTKN', '52', TO_DATE('01/01/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 16.000000, 24.000)insert into ps_tl_compleave_tbl values('4327142', 0, TO_DATE('03/23/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'LTKN', 'LTKN', '51', TO_DATE('03/23/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0.000000, 0.000)
```

The first insert succeeds but the second one gives an error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do both inserts at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems you're missing a `;` between the two statements:
`insert into ps_tl_compleave_tbl values('2626899', 0, TO_DATE('01/01/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'LTKN', 'LTKN', '52', TO_DATE('01/01/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 16.000000, 24.000)`
**`;`**
`insert into ps_tl_compleave_tbl values('4327142', 0, TO_DATE('03/23/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'LTKN', 'LTKN', '51', TO_DATE('03/23/2002', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0.000000, 0.000)`
**`;`**
Try adding the `;` and let us know.

Answer (score 16):

In .net, when we try to execute a single Oracle SQL statement with a semicolon at the end. The result will be an oracle error: ora-00911: invalid character.  OK, you figure that one SQL statement doesn't need the semicolon, but what about executing 2 SQL statement in one string for example:

```
Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("db")
Dim cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand
Dim sql As String = ""

sql = "DELETE FROM iphone_applications WHERE appid = 1; DELETE FROM iphone_applications WHERE appid = 2; "

cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql)
db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)
```

The code above will give you the same Oracle error: ora-00911: invalid character.

The solution to this problem is to wrap your 2 Oracle SQL statements with a `BEGIN` and `END;` syntax, for example:

```
sql = "BEGIN DELETE FROM iphone_applications WHERE appid = 1; DELETE FROM iphone_applications WHERE appid = 2; END;"
```

Courtesy: http://www.lazyasscoder.com/Article.aspx?id=89&title=ora-00911%3A+invalid+character+when+executing+multiple+Oracle+SQL+statements

Comment: when you are entering code in a question/answer, it is more readable if you format it as code.  The "{}" button does this for you, or you can just indent the code manually.  you can also use back ticks to mark code within a sentence.

Comment: The "lazyasscoder" link above sends me to a website that flashes using Chinese characters. Please be careful. Am, not sure whether I have got accidentally infected

Answer (score 11):

In Oracle the semi-colon ';' is only used in sqlplus. When you are using ODBC/JDBC, OLEDB, etc you don't put a semi-colon at the end of your statement. In the above case you are actually executing 2 different statements so the best way to handle the problem is use 2 statements instead of trying to combine into a single statement since you can't use the semi-colon.

Answer (score 4):

semi colon after the first insert?

Comment: Adding a semi-colon to the end of the statement gives me this error: 
ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL uses a semi-colon ;  as its end of statement marker.

you will need to add the ; after bother insert statments.

NB: that also assumes ADODB will allow 2 inserts in a single call.

the alternative might be to wrap both calls in a block,

```
BEGIN
      insert (...) into (...);
      insert (...) into (...);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my loop I was not re-initializing my StringBuilder ...thus the multiple insert statement I posted.

Thanks for your help anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but in the first insert the sql date format is valid for both uk/us, the second insert is invalid if the Oracle DB is setup for UK date format, I realise you have used the TO_DATE function but I don't see anything else ...

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET OLE DB provider is for generic data access where you don't have a specific provider for your database. Use OracleConnection et al in preference to OleDbConnection for an Oracle database connection.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the semicolon problem, I strongly recommend you look into bind variables.  Failing to use them can cause database performance problems down the road.  The code also tends to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you have a parameter variable that is null being inserted into the query. That was what my problem was. Once I gave the parameter a default value of empty string, it worked.