# Joining SQL tables and updating values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still trying to join tables and it is not running correctly when I try to run it. Also, the bottom block of input it messed up. I want output to display representing values 1-10. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT customer_id, cust_first_name
FROM demo_customers
WHERE cust_state= 'VA'
INNER JOIN demo_orders
ON demo_customers.customer_id.cust_first_name=demo_orders.order_id


SELECT order_id
FROM demo_orders
WHERE customer_id= '1'

SELECT order_item_id
FROM demo_order_items
WHERE order_id= '2'

SELECT product_name
FROM demo_product_info
WHERE product_id= <10
```

Comment: what are tables you wanna join and what do u want as your resultset?

Comment: There should be 4 tables joined. It should display A guys name, his state of residency, His order IDs and all that he ordered.

Comment: can u name the tables and the column they contain so that v can answer more appropriately.

Comment: Tables: demo_customers; demo_orders; demo_product_info; demo_order_items;

Comment: Please put up sql fiddle

Comment: It keeps saying it is not ended properly. Trying everything including watching for misspellings and double spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
demo_customers.customer_id.cust_first_name = demo_orders.order_id
```

should probably read

```
demo_customers.customer_id = demo_orders.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are after here, but something like this will provide a join on the 4 tables.

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   demo_customers
INNER JOIN demo_orders
   ON demo_customers.customer_id=demo_orders.customer_id
INNER JOIN demo_order_items
   ON demo_order.order_id = demo_order_items.order_id
INNER JOIN demo_product_info
   ON demo_product_info.product_id = demo_order_item.product_id
WHERE 
  cust_state= 'VA'
```

Comment: I don't use Oracle but it looks like you might need to end the statement with a ; (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  SELECT demo_customers.customer_id, demo_customers.cust_first_name
    FROM demo_customers c
      INNER JOIN demo_orders o
    ON demo_customers.customer_id = demo_orders.order_id
       WHERE c.cust_state= 'VA';
```

Comment: It keeps saying it is not ended properly. Trying everything including watching for misspellings and double spaces.

Comment: @Belltower What about with the semicolon?

Comment: Is this query run within a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. It seems like this command is the only one not working for me.

Comment: When you run the query by itself (outside of the procedure), does it run fine?