# what is getting wrong with query ?

Tags: oracle10g

```
INSERT INTO EMP_COMPANY(ename,cname,salary,jdate) VALUES
('ANIL','ACC',1500.00,'01-MAY-89'),
........
('AMOL','ACC',1000.00,'17-MAR-95');
```

Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended .
what is missing in syntax ?

Comment: I think Oracle only supports inserting one row using `values()`.  Use `select  . . . from dual union all` for multiple rows.

Comment: You're not asking any clear question. CAPS IN TITLE IS BAD STYLE. You don't show any attempt at solving.

Comment: I tried but it is not working . i highlighted the error which that oracle 10g ex is showing...

Comment: ok @GordonLinoff let m try your way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting an error in SQL command not properly ended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288408/im-getting-an-error-in-sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Comment: Oracle and Mysql are different database and have different syntax. Dont mix them! Your query will work on MySQL but is not a proper syntax for Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot multiple records like the way you are doing. You can try like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_COMPANY(ename,cname,salary,jdate) 
select 'ANIL','ACC',1500.00,'01-MAY-89' from dual
union all 
select 'SHANKAR','TATA',2000.00,'10-MAY-90' from dual
union all
select 'JAYA','CMC',1800.00,'7-JULY-91' from dual
union all
select 'SUNIL','CMC',1700.00,'1-JAN-88' from dual
union all
select 'VIJAY','TATA',5000.00,'3-JAN-88' from dual
union all
select 'PRAKASH','TATA',3000.00,'27-MAY-89' from dual
```

There is one more option to use `INSERT ALL` like this:

```
   INSERT ALL
   INTO EMP_COMPANY (ename,cname,salary,jdate) VALUES ('ANIL','ACC',1500.00,'01-MAY-89')
   INTO EMP_COMPANY  (ename,cname,salary,jdate) VALUES ('SHANKAR','TATA',2000.00,'10-MAY-90')
   INTO EMP_COMPANY  (ename,cname,salary,jdate) VALUES ('JAYA','CMC',1800.00,'7-JULY-91')
   ...........
   SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: thank you for other way.. but i want to tell me ..is it(insertion of multiple row) possible in way i shown it above

Comment: @Himanshu:- No that is not the correct syntax for inserting multiple records.

Comment: i am working on your syntax ..what does "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL "means here . ? but this is alternate way to solve the query .. my syntax doesnt work  in oracle database ex .. @rahul tripathi

Comment: @Himanshu:- As I said, your syntax is not correct. As far as `select 1 from dual` is concerned then you can understand it like this that INSERT ALL requires the select query.

Comment: yes your are right . there is syntax error ..