# SQL , INSERT with SELECT

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to INSERT new row with this values (hotelNo,guestNo,dataform,dataTo,roomNo)
I know the hotel name , so I have to SELECT the hotelNo from another table , it didn't work with me , is there something wrong?

```
INSERT INTO Booking
VALUES (hotelNo,123,'3-sept-1014','3-sept-1014',121)
(SELECT hotelNo
 FROM Hotel
 WHERE hotelName='Ritz Carlton' AND city='Dubai');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `VALUES (hotelNo,...` from your query and you are good to go.

```
INSERT INTO Booking
(SELECT hotelNo,123,'3-sept-1014','3-sept-1014',121
 FROM Hotel
 WHERE hotelName='Ritz Carlton' AND city='Dubai')
```

Comment: this wont work, you should remove `VALUES` from query

Comment: @BSMN: Are you sure you have 5 fields in the table?

Comment: @RagingBull yes I'm sure :(

Answer (score 3):

You should do it without `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO Booking 
(SELECT hotelNo, 123, '3-sept-1014','3-sept-1014',121
 FROM Hotel
 WHERE hotelName='Ritz Carlton' AND city='Dubai');
```

Comment: thank you but it's not work , it gives me this error: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: are you using more than one query? if so you should end every with `;`

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended

Comment: no I copy your statements  and I have just one query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (
(SELECT hotelNo
FROM Hotel
WHERE hotelName='Ritz Carlton' AND city='Dubai'),
123,'3-sept-1014','3-sept-1014',121);
```